# Which printer driver do I use? I386 or amd64?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pixel

I am trying to install a driver for epson L360 on my Raspberry Pi 3 (running Pixel). I have the following two deb files from the epson website. Which one should I be using?

epson-inkjet-printer-201401w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
epson-inkjet-printer-201401w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb

Comment: The Pi is ARM, not 386, nor AMD.  You will need to build the drivers from source,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which printer driver do I use? I386 or amd64?

Neither.  "i386" is also known as [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-32); "amd64" is also known as [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64).

All Pi's are [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) variants, and not compatible with the x86 [ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set)s.  The Pi 3 is ARMv8, which is backward compatible with ARMv6 (the single core Pis) and ARMv7 (the Pi 2).  For this reason Raspbian is ARMv6, meaning any software you run on it must be compiled for that.  There are a wider variety of ARMv7 OS distributions available for the Pi 2 and 3.  It is possible to run a 64-bit ARMv8 (aka. "aarch64") on the Pi 3, but this should still be considered experimental as it seems the kernel does not support all of the SoC's peripherals and other components on the board.

For the most part manufacturers do not distribute ARM drivers.  It is the most common ISA used on mobile devices such as smartphones, but any drivers used there are unlikely to be compatible with available Pi operating systems.

In short you are out of luck.

Comment: Managed to extract the Deb file to get a PPD file. Managed to install the driver using CUPS. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: there are often other binary filter programs involved in a driver beyond the ppd

Comment: For posterity, perhaps the good news was premature: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/60361/5538

Answer (score 3):

I installed additional packages and used L210's driver. It seems to work.

```
sudo apt-get install foomatic-filters
sudo apt-get install foomatic-db-engine
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-escpr
```

EPSON_L360_Series   EPSON L360 Series       Epson L210 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.11    Idle

Comment: This is the ideal way to go if appropriate drivers are available via `apt` since they will be properly compiled for the platform.

Answer (score 2):

I've got something that might work. Can't test it as I haven't got that kind of printer. It's based on [this](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-964750-start-0.html).

You'll likely need to install a bunch of things first

```
sudo apt install lsb-base build-essential automake autoconf system-config-printer libcups2-dev libcupsimage2-dev cups alien
```

Download the `epson-inkjet-printer-201401w-1.0.0-1lsb3.2.src.rpm`, then extract it:

```
rpm2cpio epson-inkjet-printer-201401w-1.0.0-1lsb3.2.src.rpm  | cpio -idmv
```

Extract the filter:

```
tar xvzf epson-inkjet-printer-filter-1.0.0.tar.gz
```

Build it:

```
cd epson-inkjet-printer-filter-1.0.0
libtoolize --force --copy
aclocal
autoconf
automake --add-missing
./configure --prefix=/opt/epson-inkjet-printer-201401w
make
sudo make install
cd ..
```

Now extract the other archive, `epson-inkjet-printer-201401w-1.0.0.tar.gz` and move the support files into place:

```
tar xvzf epson-inkjet-printer-201401w-1.0.0.tar.gz
sudo mv epson-inkjet-printer-201401w-1.0.0/ppds /opt/epson-inkjet-printer-201401w
sudo mv epson-inkjet-printer-201401w-1.0.0/watermark /opt/epson-inkjet-printer-201401w
```

Now try installing the printer again - you should be able to use the graphical printer configuration. Again: I *don't* know if this works, as I don't have the printer, but at least it builds the binary filter and puts the PPD files where the system might expect them.

Comment: Trying - will update to you if this works... Thanks!

Comment: Followed your instructions and tried to add the printer in CUPS using the PPD file. Didn't work. I get the following error on CUPS - "Filter failed"

Comment: I have the same issue, CUPS error "Filter failed"